# How to fetch specific data against id in Laravel with joins?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I've been working on a Laravel project. Everything is done but i'm stuck on a Laravel database query from where i need to fetch the data. The tables are:

Products and Categories.

I'm passing Products id as a parameter in my controller function but i don't know how to fetch products with the same category. Below is the code i'm writing in my controller:

```
public function details($id)
    {

/*        $rel = DB::select('select products.id,products.name,products.description,products.image,products.price,products.category_id,categories.id,categories.name From products INNER JOIN categories on products.category_id = categories.id where category_id = $id');*/

        $rel = DB::select(`products.id`,`products.name`,`products.description`,`products.image`,`products.price`,`products.category_id`,`categories.id`,`categories.name`)->from(`products`)->join(`categories`, function($join) {
            $join->on(`products.category_id`, `=`, `categories.id`);
            })->where($id'.category_id', `=`,'id' )->get();

        $products = Product::all();
        $product = Product::Find($id);
        dd($rel);
        return view('front.singleproduct',compact(['product','products','rel']));
    }
```

Here's the database fields i need to access: 
[image]

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: can you include your product and category model in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
Category::Find($id)->products;
```

fetches the products against a product id.